# Sum by two groups in R and create a panel

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have the following dataset:

```
  id_municipio   ano CLARO    OI   TIM  VIVO
1      1300029  1999     0     5     0     0
2      1300029  2006     0     2     0     0
3      1300029  2012     0     0     0     2
4      1300029  2015     0     2     0     0
5      1300029  2016     2     0     0     2
6      1300029  2022     0     0     1     0
```

I want to sum "CLARO", "OI", "TIM", and "VIVO" by "id_municipio", and "ano". So, I would have the following panel:

```
  id_municipio   ano CLARO    OI   TIM  VIVO
1      1300029  1999     0     5     0     0
2      1300029  2006     0     7     0     0
3      1300029  2012     0     7     0     2
4      1300029  2015     0     9     0     2
5      1300029  2016     2     9     0     4
6      1300029  2022     2     9     1     4
```

I know it should be something like this, but I keep getting the original dataset. What am I doing wrong?

```
teste_3 <- teste_2 %>%
    group_by(id_municipio, ano) %>%
    arrange(ano) %>%
    mutate(
        CLARO = cumsum(CLARO),
        OI = cumsum(OI),
        TIM = cumsum(TIM),
        VIVO = cumsum(VIVO)
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could manage to solve this issue by dropping "ano" from the code.

```
teste_3 <- teste_2 %>%
    group_by(id_municipio, ano) %>%
    arrange(ano) %>%
    mutate(
        CLARO = cumsum(CLARO),
        OI = cumsum(OI),
        TIM = cumsum(TIM),
        VIVO = cumsum(VIVO)
    )
```